# May a person give his father a haircut?

Tags: halacha, hair, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Per [Yoreh Deah 241:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=390) one should not take out a thorn embedded in his father as it may cause a wound. One should also not do a phlebotomy on his father. I have heard people saying that this would extend to haircuts also as at times it may lead to slight bleeding. Is there a source for this one way or the other?

Comment: Haircuts lead to bleeding?

Comment: I don't know how this could lead to bleeding. Maybe just don't shave the back of the neck?

Comment: If the fellow has a pimple perhaps? I also think the answer is that there is no problem, however someone told me there is a problem and I would like to verify either way.

Answer (score 6):

Leket Hayosher Yoreh Deah page 37 says that it is prohibited since it may cause bleeding.

However in the Sefer Moreh Horim U'Kevodom 10:12 it brings down in the name of Rabbi Ben Zion Abba Shaul Zatzal that a son may trim his father's nails and cut his hair.

Also the Debreziner in [Shaalos U'Teshuvos Beer Moshe 4:84](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14710&st=%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%97+%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95&pgnum=414&hilite=e17c6b0e-33d5-474f-938a-32e44f59fa0c) permits a child to cut his fathers hair.

Comment: What about Shelihuth?  If someone hires a nurse to care for his or her parents in their old age, according to the opinion that the person cannot cut his own father's hair/nails, can the nurse do so?

Comment: I do not know. I guess you have a good question to ask.

Comment: @SethJ I imagine it's fine. People hire doctors to do surgery on their parents all the time.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I suppose, though, that a child may not perform surgery on a parent, even if the child is the only qualified person to do so? And then, what about an emergency situation (general surgeon taking vacation with his father, father experiences sudden, severe abdominal pain while hiking, surgeon realizes it's the appendix and that it will burst before they can get to the nearest hospital, but has sterile emergency medical equipment in his bag for just that type of situation and can remove the appendix and suture the wound in under an hour and then take his dad to the ER.

Comment: @SethJ, as you know, emergencies trump the sin of wounding a parent.

Comment: @msh210 That's true from a pikuach nefesh standpoint, but what about where it isn't pikuach nefesh? .....

Comment: .... @SethJ in those cases http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e305.htm#7